# Creating Intranet GIS application

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap

I am working about task for custom GIS application (about 70 users). It must show a map of region with custom objects from database (they will be triangles, lines, and icons with coordinates) . Users can add objects to the map by clicking the mouse. I am reading now about OSM, tiles servers and other information. But I don't know how to start creating the architecture of an application. Could you give some advices or examples of such applications (I think somebody has done such projects). Will I need ArcGIS and what plan? Or can I use only OSM with Leaflet?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user, please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).  Unfortunately, this question is very broad, and doesn't fit well with the focused question/best answer model used here.  You may need a GIS/IT architecture expert to help resolve the myriad of issues raised in this question.

Comment: crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419105/gis-application-for-intranet

Comment: If you don't know how to even *start* creating the architecture, why are you even trying? Employ someone who does. This doesn't look remotely like your job.

Comment: Yeah really, the above posters are correct.  You need to figure out your very basic requirements first....  Do you want to do this with only open source software?  Proprietary solutions?  A stack of various libraries or a homogenous environment?  Scalability?  etc.  Only once you figure out those requirements can you even start planning the architecture.  Stack Exchange can't really help you out here in the QA format.  You need an expert/consultant.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would use Three-Tier architecture:

1. Database
2. GIS Server
3. Front-end application & frameworks

For each tier, there are proprietary or open source solutions like:

- Database: PostGIS, Mysql, Oracle, SQL Server,...
- GIS Server: GeoServer, MapServer, ArcGIS Server,...
- Front-end: OpenLayers, GeoExt,
  Javascript API for ArcGIS, Leaflet...

Answer (score 0):

MVC architecture can fit here you can read more here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Modern_web_app_architecture

Additional information about web design can be found here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658099.aspx

Comment: This does not really answer the question. MVC is a useful development framework, but is far too wide a concept to be an answer to creating an intranet GIS application.